# JavaEE/Primefaces: ConfirmDialog does not appear

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces

I'm having an issue with JavaEE and Primefaces.

I have a data table with a button for deleting an entry. The button works like a charm.

I want a confirm dialog before deleting the entry but I faced the issue here. The confirm dialog is in the code but it doesn't appear.The action is executed instant after clicking the button.

When I click on a button (in the example the edit button) without any special functionality before, the confirm dialog for the delete button works.

Here is the .xhtml file:

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <h1>ProbeType overview</h1>
        <p>Use this site to view available probetypes and if necessary to
            edit them.</p>
        <h:form id="probelist">

                <p:column style="width: 40px">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-pencil" id="btnEdit"
                        action="#{editProbeBean.editProbeType(probetype)}" update="@all" />
                </p:column>
                <p:column style="width: 40px">
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-cancel" id="btnDel"
                        action="#{probeBean.deleteProbeType(probetype)}" update="@all">
                        <p:confirm header="Confirm"
                            message="Would you like to delete this probetype with all corresponding data?"
                            icon="ui-icon-alert"></p:confirm>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
        <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" id="btnYes"
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
            <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
                styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </ui:define>
```

Here is the Bean file:

```
public class ProbeBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private List<ProbeType> probetypes;

@Inject
private ProbeTypeFacadeLocal probeTypeFacade;

public List<ProbeType> getProbeTypes() {
    probetypes = probeTypeFacade.getAllProbeTypes();
    return probetypes;
}

public String deleteProbeType(ProbeType probe) {
    try {
        probeTypeFacade.deleteProbeType(probe);
        probetypes = probeTypeFacade.getAllProbeTypes();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("errors", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "Error!", "Error while deleting, are there still Jobs in database?"));
    }
    return "probelist.xhtml";
}
```

The solution might be simple but I'll be grateful if anyone help me to figure out with the solution.

Comment: Try to add your confirmDialog a widgetVar e.g. widgetVar="confirmVar" then add a onClick event to your button to let the confirmDialog appear e.g. onclick="PF('confirmVar').show();"

Comment: I tried this, but its the same behaviour as before.

Comment: Try to place the <p:confirmDialog /> inside your form element as in the primefaces example https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/confirmDialog.xhtml

Comment: I already tried this, it don't work either..